# Select where in list of list

Tags: python, list, select, where-clause

I have a list of lists with this kind of data:

```
data = [[[1], 1, "A", [1,2], "ab"],
        [[2], 2, "B", [2,1], "bc"],
        [[2], 2, "C", [2,1], "bc"]]
```

Is their in python a simple method to get the sublist of all elements which fullfill some specific condition, e.g. get all elements where third element equals to "A"? More general is their a way to pass select where statements on that list of lists?

Comment: can you give more details on the generalization?

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this? Did you try using a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[l for l in data if l[2] == 'A']
```

output:

```
[[[1], 1, 'A', [1, 2], 'ab']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[2] == 'A', data)
```

output:

```sh
[[[1], 1, 'A', [1, 2], 'ab']]
```